# Enter a value into a struct pointer

Tags: c

I make code like this:

```
typedef struct t_node{
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int info;
}node;

typedef struct t_node *Tree;
```

then I use this procedure to create the tree , it's just a simple procedure

```
void createTree(Tree *T){
    (*T)->info = NULL;
}
```

But I get error about assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast and I can't understand it.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: `(*T)->info = nil;` ==> `T->info = nil;`, if `nil` is an `int` or similar.

Comment: sorry,, nil mean NULL

Comment: `NULL` is a pointer, `info` is an `int`, that does not match.

Comment: As a rule, don't include pointers in `typedef` definitions.  It hides the fact that the type is a pointer and can cause confusion to those reading your code, including yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`(*T)->info` is an `int` as `info` is declared `int` in structure. `NULL` is a pointer.

Comment: how do I enter NULL in ( * T ) - > Info ?

Comment: You can't. Both are of different type.

Answer (score 2):

When you use (*Tree), you de-reference the pointer, but then you de-reference it again, by using (*Tree)-> which is the equivalent of (*(*Tree)).

In short, either use

```
(*T).info = NULL;
```

or

```
T->info = NULL;
```

In your case though, I see that this is warranted since Tree is a typedef of struct node* ,so what you're doing is correct.

NULL is 0 cast to a pointer, and that is giving you compilation errors since info is a int and not a pointer. change 'NULL' to '0'.

Comment: No. Your answer is wrong. `Tree` is of type `struct t_node *`. It means that `T` in `Tree *T` is of type `struct t_node **`. Therefore, `(*T)->info` is correct.

Comment: Double wrong, as "NULL is *not* just a define to 0".  It's a `((void*)0)`, i.e. cast to a pointer. This is the reason the warning is issued (since *info* is an int). Replace NULL with 0 and the prog compiles fine.